# ImportError: cannot import name '_print_elapsed_time'

Tags: scikit-learn, importerror

Hi so I'm trying to use the make_pipeline module in sklearn. But when I try to import it with:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_print_elapsed_time'
```

I've googled it but there seems to be no other posts about this. I tried reinstalling scikitlearn but I still get the same error :/ Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug introduced into one of the newer versions of scikit-learn (I got this same issue in version 0.21.2).

I was able to fix this by downgrading to scikit-learn version 0.20.0

```
>> pip install scikit-learn==0.20.0
```