# sklearn: cannot import name '_print_elapsed_time' from 'sklearn.utils' when using PDP feature

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn version 0.22.1 (the latest one as of this writing).

When I do:

```
from sklearn.inspection import partial_dependence
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence
```

it reported an error:

`ImportError: cannot import name '_print_elapsed_time' from 'sklearn.utils'`

I consulted the page [ImportError: cannot import name '_print_elapsed_time'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566901/importerror-cannot-import-name-print-elapsed-time) but the solution there (downgrading to sklearn 0.20) does not work for me as the PDP is available only in sklearn 0.22.1

How could I fix the problem? It is quite strange as I followed exactly the example on sklearn website https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence.html#sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566901/importerror-cannot-import-name-print-elapsed-time